# how to set IP address to a computer using a C program?

Tags: c, networking, network-programming, ip-address

i have a hard code(C code) to print my computer IP address, i'll alter my IP with some requirements and finally i can print the updated IP on screen. now the problem is, i need to set the altered IP address to my computer. anyone please help me in setting a new IP address to a computer using C language as platform.
my hard code and its output is attached below.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
int n,chain=2,ADU=2,cam_port=2,IP=0,formulae,stream_num=3;
struct ifreq ifr;
char array[] = "eth0";
int int_val = 0;
int c = 0;
char *some_addr;


n = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);

ifr.ifr_addr.sa_family = AF_INET;

strncpy(ifr.ifr_name , array , IFNAMSIZ - 1);
ioctl(n, SIOCGIFADDR, &ifr);
close(n);
printf("IP Address is %s - %s\n" , array , inet_ntoa(( (struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr) );

some_addr = inet_ntoa(( (struct sockaddr_in *)&ifr.ifr_addr )->sin_addr); 
printf("The last character octet  is %c%c%c\n", some_addr[11],some_addr[12],some_addr[13]); 

for (c = 11; some_addr[c]!= '\0'; c++) 
 {
   int_val = int_val * 10 + some_addr[c] - '0';
 }


printf("int value = %d\n", int_val); 
IP = int_val;


formulae=((chain-1)*128) + ((ADU-1)*32) + ((cam_port-1)*4) + (stream_num+1);
IP=formulae;
printf("updated IP is 239.192.140.%d\n",IP);
return 0;
}
```

output:

> IP Address is eth0 - 192.168.15.91
>       The last character octet  is 91
>       int value = 91
>       updated IP is 239.192.140.168

Comment: Which operating system? And why do you do this?

Comment: Way too many dependencies from external factors to provide an answer - You might have DHCP activated, in that case it isn't even decided on your computer what IP adress it is going to receive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set the IP address from C in linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652384/how-to-set-the-ip-address-from-c-in-linux)

Comment: This might help you, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308090/set-ip-address-using-siocsifaddr-ioctl

Comment: You example updated IP address is a multicast address, and you are not allowed to assign it to an interface. Multicast addresses cannot be source addresses, as would be the case with assigning one to an interface.

Answer (score 0):

You're already using `ioctl(SIOCGIFADDR` to get the interface address, so once you change it in `ifreq` struct, you can then do `ioctl(SIOCSIFADDR` to set it.  Unsuprisingly, that's what the `G` and `S` characters mean the ioctl names (get and set).