# How IP address is informed to linux kernel?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

On system boot up, dhclient gets the IP address over particular network interface, how is this information(IP address) passed to kernel?

Comment: Are you interested in a high level explanation or an explicit flow containing the device drivers involved and/or the specific system calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, using `SIOCSIFADDR` ioctl. 
More information about user-space program which does that: [Set IP address using SIOCSIFADDR ioctl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308090/set-ip-address-using-siocsifaddr-ioctl)